# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while running application

Tags: java, database, jdbc

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` I am getting this error while running my struts application. 
like:

> Failed to instantiate JDBC driver class from `database.properties`

Which jar file need to add to this project?

Comment: Put the `sqljdbc.jar` and `sqljdbc4.jar` inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: is google down? Download from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `JDBC` driver is not part of the Java SDK. If you want to use it, you must set the `classpath` to include the `sqljdbc.jar` file or the `sqljdbc4.jar` file. If the `classpath` is missing an entry for `sqljdbc.jar` or `sqljdbc4.jar`, your application will throw the common "Class not found" exception.

Comment: what about JWT ? "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm"